# org.slf4j.Logger logs to console, how do I log to file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am using the org.slf4j.Logger to log output.  Output is going to console.  How do I get logging logged to a log file?

```
 private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class );
 LOG.info("Logging output to console");
```

I am not using a log4j.properties file.  I am assuming I will need one.

I added the following log4j.properties file and placed it in different parts of my eclipse project.

```
 # Define the file appender
 log4j.appender.FileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.FileAppender.File=logger.log
 log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

 # Direct all messages there
 log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FileAppender
```

I even used

```
 PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

But no logging file appears.  log4j.properties doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: i think you can use something similar to log4j.properties file or log4j.xml file

Comment: If you assume that you will need such a file, why not just try to define one? (after which you could enlighten us all...)

Comment: i had added a log4j.xml as answer that create a file every day

Comment: I created a log4j.properties and a log4j.xml file and placed them in different parts of my project but still logging goes to the console and not to a log file.

Comment: @user840930 did you get a solution?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way, I think, is to define a `FileAppender` in a log4j.properties file:

```
# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FileAppender.File=[log filename].log
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Direct all messages there
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FileAppender
```

Just replace `[log filename]` with some relevant filename. I think Log4j is able to automatically locate the file when you run the project from Eclipse if the file is in your project directory, but I'm not 100% sure. You can use `PropertyConfigurator` at the start of your application to tell Log4j where to find the properties file, e.g.:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

Comment: I created such a file log4j.properties.  But where should I put it?  I placed it different places in my eclipse project.  But no .log file seems to be created.

Comment: I added some more detail. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a log4j.xml in the resource folder.

1. Import log4j package in the class.
2. Inside the class, instantiate a logger object using Logger.getLogger( ) static method.
3. Instantiate layouts (readymade or user-defined) to be assigned to appenders.
4. Instantiate appenders and assign desired layout to them by passing the layout object as parameter to their constructors.
5. Assign the instatiated appenders to the Logger object by invoking its addAppender( ) method with desired appender as parameter.
6. Invoke appropriate printing methods on Logger object to perform logging.

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p [%t] %c{1}.%M(%L) | %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="fileNamePattern" value="/yourfolder/debug_%d{dd-MM-yy}.log" />

        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p [%t] %c{1}.%M(%L) | %m%n" />
        </layout>

    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: I don't think I have a resource folder.

Comment: could you please provide  the structure of your project.if it is a maven project you will have a src/main/resource folder i actually ment that. you can put it any where in src folder.

Comment: use log4j.xml since properties file does not provide some advanced configuration options such as Filter, some of ErrorHandlers, and few advanced Appenders

Comment: this didn't fix the problem.  I created the log4j.xml file and placed in different parts of the eclipse project.  I even copied it to the src folder and that didn't help either.  I am not using maven yet.